# Скрипт: сделать картинку цветной при наведении

Tags: скрипт, html, изображения, css, javascript

Есть даже логика: чтоб был опасити, а при наведении этот опасити плавно убирался с картинки, вроде просто. Буду благодарен кто подкинет чего-то

Comment: Цветной или полупрозрачной?

Comment: цветной. Тоесть она цветная по дефолту

Answer (score 3):

на чистом css http://jsfiddle.net/MeTcL/1/

[[@denis949](/users/15431/denis949)](/users/15431/denis949), а так http://jsfiddle.net/MeTcL/2/ ?? Если свойство опасити вам вообще не подходит, то нужно поверх картинки ставить блок, бекграундом которого будет полупрозрачное гиф или пнг изображение. И при ховере делать этому блоку display: none

Comment: Да нет, надо кроссбраузерно,а это только новеший браузеры потянут

Comment: обновил ответ

Comment: а как это сделать, чтоб еще и плавно было?? в js не разбираюсь

Comment: @denis949, ну так начните разбираться. Это уже работа за автора

Comment: мне это нужно максимум за 2 часа, js я так быстро не выучу. Ладно спасибо

Comment: Круто, максимум за 2 часа без знания js? Зачем же вы брались за это задание?

Answer (score 3):

Самый простой вариант (если не знаете js) - две картинки - черно-белая и цветная -

```
img{
  черно-белая
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; 
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;            
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; 
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; 
   transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
img:hover{
  цветная
}
```

transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out - это свойство для плавного изменения изображения

[CSS3 сейчас — transition](http://habrahabr.ru/post/111658/)